# How to put condition inside the echo statement?

Tags: php

I have this while loop inside a php statement. Inside my while loop i put echo and inside that echo is a td tag. After it is another if condition with `img src` determining from a row inside it and another echo with `br and td` tag in it. How can I resolve this?

Here is my code

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo '<tr>
                            <!--Photos first-->
                            <td><center>s';
                            if(!empty(trim($row['photo']))){
                                    echo "<img src='.$row['photo'].' class='img-circle' height='100px' width='100px'> ";
                                    echo '<br>.$row["username"]. <br></td>';
                            }
                    }
```

Error that showed

```
unexpected $EOF, expecting TSTRINg TVARIABLE T NUM STRING
```

Comment: Even if there is an issue with string concatenation / interpolation, this code should not throw that error in PHP.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone 4th last line, single quotes, within single quotes?

Comment: @saibbyweb The encapsulation appears to be correct. lines 2-4 are correctly encapsulated with single quote. Line 6 is encapsulated with double quotes (although the `src` will be wrong). Line 7 is correctly encapsulated with single quotes again (variable won't be expanded and extra `.`s displayed). None of these issues would produce that error though.

Comment: 4th last line : `echo "<img src='.$row['photo'].' class='img-circle' ...` | using single quotes for index `$row['photo']`, within single quotes used for `src`

Comment: @user3783243 PHP should claim about `T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE`, since quoted array indexes are not allowed on interpolation when not using braces `"{$array['name']}"`.

Comment: @saibbyweb That's not the point in PHP. The `src=''` HTML part is out of interest here.

Comment: @Qausimodo'sclone : It is claiming the same error. The whole line is read as a single string. Try echoing this line yourself.

Comment: Yea, looks like the wrong error message was included with the question. No `EOF` error here.

Comment: I do not get `unexpected $EOF`. Again, the problem is a quoted array index within double qouted interpolation. Both is valid: `"string with $array[name] and {$array['name']}"`

Comment: Some other part of the questioner's code might be causing `$EOF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not escaping `'` properly, try this :

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<tr>
    <!--Photos first-->
    <td><center>';
    if(!empty(trim($row['photo']))){
        echo "<img src='" . $row['photo'] . "' class='img-circle' height='100px' width='100px'> ";
        echo '<br>' .$row["username"]. '<br></td>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to use this comment section for seeking help with any other problem you have :)

Comment: How about this one sir? 

                                echo "<br> <b>Stylist Type:</b> <i> . $row['stylist_type'] . </i>";

Comment: You seem to be pretty new. It should be `echo "<br> <b>Stylist Type:</b> <i>" . $row['stylist_type'] . "</i>";` | By help, I meant if you post any question on StackOverflow and want help with it |  If you have a lot of questions, skype @ live:suhaibkhan.work :)